# snort and portscan loggin

Tags: snort

I posted a question a couple of days ago about the portscan log, however this is a separate question that deals with the new portscan logs.

Time: 04/13-15:29:41.660134
event_id: 6042
x.x.x.x -> x.x.x.x(portscan) UDP Filtered Portscan
Priority Count: 0
Connection Count: 200
IP Count: 66
Scanner IP Range:x.x.x.x:x.x.x.x
Port/Proto Count: 32
Port/Proto Range: 137:17500

I am trying to determine 4 things from this log, source IP, destination IP, source port, destination port.

Some other options i would like, but as necessary, would be the type of portscan and the flags for this scan.

Again, thanks for any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 1):

The protocol was UDP, so there are no flags available (that's a TCP thing).  The log suggests (if I am reading it correctly) that 32 ports were tested, running a range from 137 to 17500, so pick 30 ports other than 137 and 17500 and that's what got scanned.  To get more specific, you would need to find a way to deaggregate the information and break each alert into its own event and log them individually.